# Bootstrap Cards - issue with centering when viewed on mobile device

Tags: css, user-interface, bootstrap-4, frontend, user-experience

I've extensively researched this to no avail. I am using the following code to output the screenshot below it, but when viewed on a mobile device, it shifts to the left.

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row g-mb-20">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 g-mb-50 justify-content-center">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="assets/img/calisurf1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 g-mb-50 justify-content-center">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="assets/img/calisurf1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 g-mb-50 justify-content-center">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="assets/img/calisurf1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 g-mb-50 justify-content-center">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="assets/img/calisurf1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Desktop Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAjlm.png)

[Mobile Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7gh2.png)

Comment: You should add col-12, so that it takes up entire screen on mobile      
 <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3  col-12 g-mb-50 justify-content-center">

Comment: Adding col-12 or col-sm-12 does not make the card full-width. Really appreciate the idea and would love for this to happen.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I think your style="width: 18rem" caused this issue.

Comment: That was it, thanks! There is a slight margin on each edge, but I think a negative margin can fix this or perhaps 'container-fluid'. Probably Bootstrap's gutters by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add class `d-flex` to the `columns` containers (where you already have the class `justify-content-center`):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="card w-100">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="card w-100">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="card w-100">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="card w-100">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: d-flex did the trick! Thank you so much! I will be sure to come back here and upvote you once I hit that 15 rep mark. Now to figure out how to get the card full width on mobile...

Comment: Got stuck on this as well. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 0):

There is a really easy way to do this:-

```
<div class="container col-10">
    ...
</div>
```